# TeamCity, Android, Gradle Script failure

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, teamcity, android-gradle-plugin

I have been struggling to get TeamCity to build my Android Project. I have finally gotten the server to be able to compile the project with Gradlew (although I have to ignore lint errors, which I am not happy about - it will not tell me which lint errors are being violated **EDIT**: *I found it in ..\build\outputs\lint-results.html*)

But now I can see that it is trying to execute the following:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\284714bad9f1a533\MyProject>gradlew.bat --init-script C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\gradle-runner\scripts\init.gradle clean build
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\gradlerunner\scripts\init.gradle' line: 31

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> Cannot invoke method split() on null object
```

I have checked this line and it seems fairly standard:

```
initscript {
    dependencies {
        def teamCityInitLib = System.getenv("TEAMCITY_BUILD_INIT_PATH")
        println "Init lib: ${teamCityInitLib}"
        def classPathFiles = teamCityInitLib.split(File.pathSeparator) //line 31
        classpath files(classPathFiles)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? NOTE: the following command works without a problem:

```
gradlew.bat clean build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the build file is not being found. At least, that is what support is telling me. To me this is a TeamCity bug and not on my side. When I find out more, I'll post it.

Comment: You didn't find out more? I seem to have the same problem, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Eventually we ended up running the cradle build from the command line, and exporting the artifact. There was no 'easy' mechanism to do Android CI with TeamCity. We complained and they basically said that command line was the only way to go

Comment: The most ridiculous thing is that it worked yesterday before reboot. I'd hate to just do a full wipe because some environment variable has borked itself. I guess I'll spin it up in a virtual machine and get the right value for the variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't have `TEAMCITY_BUILD_INIT_PATH` variable in your PATH on your build machine. You can add it either by standart ways, depending on OS, or by adding it to Build Parameters in Configuration Steps of your build.

Comment: I can't find this variable on my build machine, are you using the latest version of teamcity?

since this variable is used to get `classPathFiles`, maybe you should point it to your project root.

Comment: Actually you should point it to the rootFolder of your teamcity installation. When you are using methods which are only known in the TC context, you also have to add it's libraries to your Path.

Comment: @questionare and how would one go and do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while looking for a way to emulate a TC build from the command line and trying to understand how to set `TEAMCITY_BUILD_INIT_PATH`.

In my environment I determined that it's set to:
`/apps/teamcity-agent/agent/lib/serviceMessages.jar:/apps/teamcity-agent/agent/lib/runtime-util.jar:/apps/teamcity-agent/agent/plugins/gradle-runner/lib/gradle-runner-common.jar`

Where `/apps/teamcity-agent` is the my TC install path.
Hope this helps.

Comment: We found our particular issue - we basically ended up building it from the Gradle.bat file as if off the command line